# Build project got the error "unable to cast object of type..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

when I build my C# project, I always got the following error window:

[image]

After restart VS and PC not work for me.

Besides, I am using Visual Studio 2015.

How to fix that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please paste the *text* of the error message into your question, never a screenshot. When a Windows message box has keyboard focus, if you press Ctrl+C, the text of the message box will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I have not enough reputation to paste a image directly instead of a link.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, OK, thanks for reminding. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix that problem?

According to the error message, it seems the Visual Studio setting of NuGet package managment have been corrupted. To resolve this error, you can try to reinstall the extension of NuGet package managment.

To accomplish this, try below steps:

1. Navigate to **Tools** -> **Extensions and Updates**, and find **Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio** and then uninstall the Nuget Package Manager.
2. After that I suggest you to restart your PC.
3. Reinstall the Nuget Package Manager via Extensions and Updates.

After reinstall the Nuget Package Manager, try to build your project.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you apply the solution described in [issue #5125 from Nuget's github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5125) as error message is the same as yours.

User Ricardosmoke wrote :

> If I close visual studio and delete all the folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions that contain a copy of Nuget, I don't get any errors about files being in use while deleting.
>
> I can then start visual studio and download and install Nuget from the Extensions gallery successfully."

You'll maybe adjust path depending of your VS version.
Example for my VS2017 community :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions

Comment: I reinstall the NuGet package managment, that works for me, also thanks for your answer. But I could not vote your answer, I have not enough reputation :(.